# Receive raw data in a virtual printer driver

Tags: c++, .net, printing, driver

I want to develop a Virtual Printer Driver in windows.
I can use port monitor and receive a PostScript stream of printing data, but that's not what i want.

I want to have access to raw data of printed document in my driver.
for example if user is printing a text file, i need to have access to actual texts in my driver, not a PostScript stream of printing document.

Can anyone please assist me?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From what I read at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, this is not possible. It's the applications task to convert the document to a standard format before sending it to the printing system. This seems logical to me, because the printing system cannot possibly know all document formats.

Comment: @Oswald: That's reasonably possible; the printing system does know about all printing formats by virtue of its drivers. And all applications must go through the GDI interface to create printer output, which boils down to `DrawText` and its friends.

Comment: Vote to close; "minimal understanding needed". Tagging the question .Net while talking about drivers should be sufficient proof.

Comment: @MSalters, That is not always true. There are two type of printer drivers, PostScript and Uni. a non-postscript PrintProcessor does not receive GDI and PostScript. it can receive rawdata and text too! you can see it here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx   In this case Driver decide to call GDI functions if its necessary. I was looking for some help on implementing this. i will post my result after i make it working.